# Custom UIButton image iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, image, ipad, button

Is it possible to have a custom UIButton that has an image covering only half of it?
I imagine it would be something like this:

```
UIButton *someButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[someButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonPicture"]];

/* Then there must be some property I can set that prevents the button from stretching the image?? */

.
.
.
```

I want to have a 50x100px button which only has a 50x50px image on the top half, and to be transparent on the bottom half.

I know how to create a custom button and everything. Im just woondering what the property is that controls the stretching of the backgroundImage.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the dimensions of the image and the rect of the button equal/proportional?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
[someButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonPicture"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
 someButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-50, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could:

1. create your button image as a 50x100px image (same size as the button);
2. make this image be half transparent (PNG with alpha),

instead of trying to assign the button a smaller image covering only half of it and prevent stretching.